# Asp.Net Core EF Core Table Joins

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two Objects, let says Employee and Address as follows

```
public class Employee
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId {get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship model is that each employee belongs to a single department (using DepartmentID property)

I want to create a view which shows all employees and instead of displaying the department ID, the department name is shown instead

My controller looks like this

> public class EmployeeController : Controller
>       {
>           private readonly IAppRepository _appRepository;
>
> ```
>     public EmployeeController(IAppRepository appRepository)
>     {
>         _appRepository = appRepository;
>     }
> ```
>
> public ViewResult List
>           {
>
> ```
>         Department department;
>
>         // retrieve all employee from DBContext (SQL Server)
>         var model = _appRepository.GetEmployees;
>
>         // retrieve department details
>         department = _appRepository.GetDepartment(model.DepartmentId);
>         ViewBag.department = department;
>       }
> ```
>
> }

My problem seems to be with the last two lines (//retrieve department details. as model is returning an enumerable of employee.

How can this be achieved, I was thinking using ViewModel but have not found a way yet.  thanks

Comment: It's look like you have some king of repository implementation, the fix should be done there. 
Probably instead of single object, GetDepartment method returns an enumerable.
Check it by yourself, or paste the code from that method here.

Comment: You don't show any EF Core code in the question, just some repository classes that seem to just load everything in memory. Looks like you've used the repository **anti**pattern that makes working with ORMs like EF Core a lot harder. In any case, you *don't* need JOINS with ORMs. JOINs are generated by the ORM itself based on the relations and navigation properties between entities

Comment: A good first step would be do delete every repository class. Create one DbContext-derived class with Employee and Department entity sets. The employee should have a `Department` property and `Department` should have an `Employees` collection. This way, if you want to retrieve an employee's department, all you'd have to do is access the Department property. EF Core itself will generate the JOIN

Comment: It's worth reading Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) where he explains just a few of the problems and *dangers* caused by adding low-level repositories on top of higher level ORMs

Comment: Just notice, that there is some inefficient approach, you should retrieve all data using single query. Passing a method to the repository looks at least weird (if the code is correct).
So yes, paste all the code from repository.
I completely agree, that repository pattern is obsolete with EF Core

Comment: With EF Core, a query that returns the employee and department name would look as simple as : ` myContext.Employees.Where(someFilter).Select(emp=>new {emp.Name,DeptName=emp.Department.Name});`. If you wanted to eagerly load employees and departments you'd have to add `Include()`, otherwise related entities are loaded in a lazy manner. Eg: `myContext.Employees.Include(emp=>emp.Department).Where(...)`. You *don't* need `Include` to perform the join, you need it for eager loading

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for this explanation.  I'm fairly novice at this.  If I understand you correctly, you are sating that we should not use a repository class and dependency injection, but access the DBContext directly in the MVC Controller class and that  no joins are needed in the LINQ queries as EF Core will know the relationship.   Could you point me to an example to see how this will look.  thank you

Comment: DI is fine, it's the repositories that cause trouble. The ASP.NET Core tutorials already show how to use EF Core, create DbContexts, inject them into controllers etc. Check the [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) tutorials

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could configure relationships between `Employee` and `Department`,refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns)

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In your repository `GetEmployees`, you could get all employees with their own `Department` using `Include`, refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

```
var employees = _context.Employees.Include(e => e.Department).ToList();
```

Then your `model` of `var model = _appRepository.GetEmployees;` will contains Department info for each employee and you could achieve name in view,for example

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes this is working now.  I was working with DB First model and I did not have a FK defined.

Comment: @Matthew Yes,you need to use code-first after you change the model.Could you accept the answer if you have resolved the problem?